# ValueChanged event in windows XP

Tags: c#

I have an ValueChanged event where I am checking dates and displaying a message to user and I set the value of the DateTimePicker to another value. This is the event:

```
private void dtpStartDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (frmDate.Value < this.minDate)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Date not found");
        frmDate.Value = previousValue;
        return;
    }
}
```

This works fine in Windows 7 but it displays the message box two times in Windows XP. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have .NET 2.0 installed on your Win 7 box or is it running your application under .NET 4?

Comment: on windows7 I am using .Net framework 3.5 same is ins installed on xp. I am using visual studio 2010 for development.

Answer (score 0):

Just dirty if you dont want to spend much effort :)

```
private DateTime _lastDate;
private void dtpStartDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_lastDate != frmDate.Value) {
        _lastDate = frmDate.Value;
        if (_lastDate < this.minDate)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Date not found");
            frmDate.Value = previousValue;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way. The DateTimePicker class has MaxDate and MinDate properties to handle that.  Just set those in your designer or at runtime when the form loads or whenever it makes sense, then you don't have to worry about the event at all, no one will be able to pick an invalid date.